# Tabulator 5.4, set individual color to each group header

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Table data is loaded from JSON. JSON contains color. How to set the color to each group header row?

Now, I able to set color to child contents of the tabulator-group row.

```
groupHeader: function(value, count, data) {
    return '<span class="group-content" style="color:'+data[0].color+'">'+value +'<span class="count">'+count+'</span></span>';
},
```

Style for the regular row (except group header) can be set like so:

```
rowFormatter:function(row){
    var data = row.getData();
    row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = data.color;
},
```

But how to apply style to the parent (group header) row element? The idea is to set individual color to every group header row, based on the JSON response.

Comment: Great you solved the problem.  SO is not a forum though, and using 'solved' in titles is discouraged - instead accept your answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-does-stack-overflow-discourage-adding-solved-to-question-titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, it was easier than expected:

```
groupHeader: function(value, count, data, group) {
    group.getElement().style.backgroundColor = data[0].color;
    return '<span class="group-content">'+value +'<span class="count">'+count+'</span></span>';
},
```